# Converting strings like 86.678, 1.12517, 0.61457 to numbers and increment/decrement last 3 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to convert strings like 86.678, 1.12517, 0.61457 to numbers, without loosing any decimal point information and amount of numbers.

numbers are different in nature, but I need a way to figure out how to increment/decrement last 2 digits of each such number by 30 so for example if I want to increment 86.678 it would become 86.708 I'm having trouble figuring this out as each time there is different amount of numbers after period `.` but there is always at least 3, also there will be cases like 89.990 where numbers will need to grow so 90.020 will be new one, same applies to decrement.

Comment: Try parseFloat - it should do the trick.  Then add 0.030.

Comment: @user2182349 That delta value fluctuates based on precision.

Comment: @user2182349 The thing is if there are more than 3 numbers after so like .004567 adding 0.030 will not work, as I need to increment just last 2 numbers in every scenario

Comment: 89.990 + 0.030 = 90.020, right?

Comment: @tadman wow, fixed..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? This is an odd thing to do and it's hard to see what it might mean mathematically. What's more, there's the problem that JavaScript numerics involve binary floating point, not decimal floating point, some some non-repeating fractions in base 10 notation are repeating fractions in base 2.

Comment: @Pointy really hard to explain, but these are coordinates and they vary so much due to things like scale, dimension etc.. being applied, this is for a mini game I'm building for practice with character walking different planets etc.. but adding 30 to last two numbers is what I need.

Comment: I see you found and accepted solution, but just wanted to mention that an alternate solution could be to parse the number as two integers which would make the addition easy,  and then combine to form the float

Comment: @holroy Thats a clever trick as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty messy and ugly, but for well formed data it should work.

```
function incrementalize(value) {
  return parseFloat(value) +
    parseFloat(value.replace(/\d/g, 0).replace(/00$/, '30'));
}
```

The first regular expression here zeroes out everything, so `123.4567` becomes `000.0000`, and then the trailing pair of zeroes are switched out, so you get `000.0030`. That's added to your original value.

Note that when adding numbers with fractional values, the inherent imprecision of IEEE-754 double-precision numbers can show up. It does, for instance, with your 0.61457 + 0.00030 example.

**Live Example:**

```js
test(86.678);
test(1.12517);
test(0.61457);
test(0.0123);
test(0.9999);

function incrementalize(value) {
  return parseFloat(value) +
    parseFloat(value.replace(/\d/g, 0).replace(/00$/, '30'));
}

function test(num) {
  var newNum = incrementalize(String(num));
  snippet.log(num + " => " + newNum);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

**Update**: To keep the precision in the initial value, using the [sprintf-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprintf-js) library:

```
function incrementalize(value) {
  return sprintf(
    '%.' + value.split(/\./)[1].length + 'f', 
    parseFloat(value) +
      parseFloat(value.replace(/\d/g, 0).replace(/00$/, '30'))
  );
}
```

Comment: It may be messy, but it's simple and should work, even with leading zeros in the fractional portion (`1.0001`) and issues like `0.999`. My solution does not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not a fan of using strings to manipulate numbers but otherwise `1.010` and `1.01` are equivalent so this is really the only way to crack this nut unless a precision value is specified as a second factor.

Comment: Given the requirement, barring some fairly complex math that could well end up exacerbating accumulated floating-point errors, I think this is great (FWIW). Took the liberty of adding a live example and a note about floating-point errors.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well in your original answer, it might work to stick a "1" on the left of the fraction part, convert to integer, add 30, convert the result to a string, strip off the leading 1 or 2 digits (to get back to the original length), parse that, subtract 1, add that to the left part, and then glue them back together. Or else, go back to an earlier stage of design and re-think why doing something this weird seemed like a good idea.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the caveat. I've always considered floating point numbers to be approximations of values rather than mathematically dependable like integers tend to be.

Comment: @Pointy: Took at stab at the "1" thing, it gets complicated in edge cases (like `0.999`). They're solveable, of course. The above is much simpler. :-)

Comment: @tadman I just realised that parse float will return 123 in cases like 123.000  is there a way to keep all decimal places even if they are zeros?

Comment: Not as a number. You'll need to format it with a tool like [sprintf-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprintf-js). Remember the internal floating point representation does not track how many places the number should have.

Comment: @Ilja Added a version here that returns a string. This makes a *lot* of assumptions about what sort of data you're feeding in.